# Django form submission not refreshing what user sees

Tags: python, django

In my django app, I've got a form that `POSTS` to the same page it's on (no AJAX or anything; super simple). I'm using an `inlineformset_factory` form.

One of my attributes is part of a many2many relationship, and thus has a `delete` checkbox. If the user checks that box and submits the form, the `POST` goes through successfully and the page refreshes (as does a normal form submission, sans-ajax).

But, when the page loads again, the items that were supposedly deleted still show up. The catch is, if I do a hard refresh of the page, they go away (because the `POST` was successful.

I'm prefixing the view functions I'm using with `@never_cache`. Otherwise, I've got nothing fancy going on and no JavaScript interacting with this form.

Any ideas? I've been stuck on this (and am a django n00b, which doesn't help).

Comment: Blindly guessing, you might be retrieving the items in the database before doing the delete action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it is good practice to redirect after a successful post, to prevent multiple submissions. Redirecting to the same url is okay.

```
if formset.is_valid():
    formset.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("")
```

The browser will follow the redirect, and the deleted items will not be displayed.